# Why my Q&As are getting downvoted without any explanation?

Tags: support

Why the questions that I answer myself are getting downvoted without any comments or reasons? Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75853988/physical-motions-are-not-smooth-despite-high-fps) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889781/how-to-use-input-system-packages-split-screen). I removed my answer posted on first one.

Comment: Up- or down-votes don't require any explanations. This has been discussed here already ad nauseam.

Comment: Explanation: a user saw the question and decided it was not useful. That is *per post*, I'm not implying it's the same user that saw each post. End of explanation.

Comment: The second question just seems to say "How do I use this feature that has a checkbox?" The answer to that usually seems to be check the checkbox...

Comment: You should also be aware that, by linking to those posts, you've invoked the Meta Effect: questions linked to from Meta posts are subject to more scrutiny than they would have been otherwise.

Comment: One down-vote seems a bit much to warrant a complaint on meta, and unfortunately can now lead to more down-votes due to a non unexpected [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect).

Comment: Quick flowchart for Unity issues: do you believe the problem *is because of code that you wrote*? No: then it is off topic. Yes: then it can be posted here, but it is still subject to all the usual expectations for diagnosing the problem, figuring out a MRE etc. Don't know: then it is your responsibility to try to figure that out before posting here.

Answer (score 10):

Your linked questions are off-topic because they are not about programming, so that is probably why they are being downvoted.

Comment: So do you mean that questions that are about unity but are not directly about c# & unity programming, should not be posted here?

Comment: @Matin Correct, questions about Unity that are not about programming (whether in C# or some other language supported by Unity) are off-topic. Unity is a game development tool. You can ask questions about Unity (including questions that involve some programming) on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. After migration it immediately got upvotes.

Comment: "So do you mean that questions that are about unity but are not directly about c# & unity programming, should not be posted here?" - Your question isn't about programming Unity code, if it were, you would have provided MRE.  If it was about Unity (code), and you didn't provide a MRE, that also would explain the downvote you received.

Comment: Hold on, we have a migration option for gamedev.se?

Comment: Just asked the mod to do that. Custom flag message